# Account for null values when mapping an array ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

This is I'm mapping an array successfully..

```
const faculty = props.faculty;

{(faculty.science_department || []).map(science_dep => (
    <div className="row">
        <p>{science_dep.name} : {science_dep.start_date}</p>
    </div>
))}
```

But what if the array is empty? How can I account for null values/empty states? How can I check within this map function? Ie: show

```
<p>There are no faculty members within this category</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what if the array is empty? How can I account for null
>   values/empty states? How can I check within this map function? Ie: show
>
> ```
> <p>There are no faculty members within this category</p>
> ```

Given those requirements I would first filter the array, then render it with the map if it contains anything, otherwise render the placeholder message:

```
const {faculty} = this.props;
const science_department = (faculty.science_department || []).filter(dep => !!dep);

{ 
    science_department.length ? science_department.map(science_dep => (
        <div className="row" key={warning.id}>
            <p>{science_dep.name} : {science_dep.start_date}</p>
        </div>)
    : 
        <p>There are no faculty members within this category</p> 
}
```

PS: What is `warning.id`? The `key` should be a field of the `science_dep` with a unique value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to do this within JSX syntax, then you can use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
const faculty = props.faculty;

{
  faculty.science_department.length !== 0 ?    
    faculty.science_department.map(science_dep => (
      <div className="row" key={warning.id}>
        <p>{science_dep.name} : {science_dep.start_date}</p>
      </div>
    ))
  :
    <p>There are no faculty members within this category</p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{(faculty.science_department || []).length ? faculty.science_department.map(science_dep => (
<div className="row" key={warning.id}>
    <p>{science_dep.name} : {science_dep.start_date}</p>
</div>
)) : (science_dep => (
<div className="row" key={warning.id}>
    <p>There are no faculty members within this category</p>
</div>)()}
```

Comment: Seems to throw an unexpected token error regarding   `</div>)()}`

Comment: do you want to assign the "<div> ..." to a variable or attach it to a dom element ?